# Unable to add restriction to bean in apache cxf soap service

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, wsdl, cxf

I am trying to add restriction to wsdl using @Facet annotation in `Employee` class but in generated wsdl restriction is not getting created.I am following [this](http://www.infosys.tuwien.ac.at/staff/hummer/tools/jaxb-facets.html)
article but still it's not working.Below is the code.
1)`Employee.java`

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.Facets;

public class Employee {

    @Facets(minInclusive="1",maxInclusive="10")
    int id;
    @Facets(pattern="[a-z][a-z0-9]{0,4}")
    String name;
    EmployeeRole role;

    //getter and setter
}
```

2)type defination in `mployeeservice.wsdl`

```
  <xs:complexType name="employee">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="role" type="tns:employeeRole"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Above wsdl does not contain `<xs:restriction>` for employee.

Please help me in this.